# Can't Install codecs ( Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock )

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, dpkg

I used the commands at the end of this article to try installing the restricted extras the article recommends.  http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/7-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

When I input this command in the terminal, I receive the following error message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
rick@rick-XPS-L521X:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
rick@rick-XPS-L521X:~$ sudo apt-get install libavformat-extra-53 libavcodec-extra-53
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
rick@rick-XPS-L521X:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
[sudo] password for rick: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

The first time I tried installing the restricted extras, the terminal brought me to a legal approval page which ended with no way to agree or not agree to the terms.  So I exited and tried to install again but then received the error message.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This either means that you are already running apt-get (could be via Software Center), or that the lock has not been properly been released last time.

If you are sure that no ongoing process is running you can try deleting the lock file.

Comment: How do i delete the lock file?

Comment: sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock

You may need to run sudo apt-get update afterwards.

Comment: Also, check the duplicate's answer.